# Timestamp (milliseconds) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I am receiving a creation date for an object in a database as milliseconds (# of milliseconds since epoch or whatever) and would like to convert it to/from a string in Swift!

I think I'd need a data type of CUnsignedLong?
I am trying something like this but it outputs the wrong number:

```
    var trial: CUnsignedLong = 1397016000000
    println(trial)  //outputs 1151628800 instead!
```

I'm guess this is the wrong data type so what would you all advise in a situation like this?
In Java I was using long which worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On 32-bit platforms, `CUnsignedLong` is a 32-bit integer, which is not large
enough to hold the number 1397016000000. (This is different from Java, where
`long` is generally a 64-bit integer.)

You can use `UInt64` or `NSTimeInterval` (a type alias for `Double`), which is what the 
`NSDate` methods use.

Comment: this is a dumb question but would that work on all versions of iPhone? i.e. is iPhone 4 32 bit? b/c i'm just thinking now it works on my old android apps

Comment: @user3379785: Yes, UInt64 and NSTimeInterval/Double work on all iOS devices (32 or 64 bit).

Answer (score 6):

```
 func currentTimeMillis() -> Int64{
    let nowDouble = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    return Int64(nowDouble*1000)
}
```

> Working fine